# jQuery make child element and parent element show on hover and fade out when not

Tags: jquery

I need my dropdown menu to be able to show on hover, and keep it visible while on hover on `.dropdown-menu-about` and on `#about`.

At the moment it shows on hover when I'm on the `#about` li but when I move my mouse over the `div` I fades out already. How would I be able to make it show on the `.dropdown-menu-about` class while on hover as well, and then fade out when it's not on hover anymore?

```
$('#about').hover(
  // on mouse in
  function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu-about').addClass('fadeIn');
  },
  // on mouse out
  function(){
      $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu-about').removeClass('fadeIn');
      $(this).parent().find('.dropdown-menu-about').addClass('fadeOut');
  }
)
```

```css
.dropdown-menu-about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    width: 500px;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
}

.m-fadeOut {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 300ms, opacity 300ms;
  }
  .m-fadeIn {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 300ms;
  }
```

```
<li>
<a href="#" id="about">About</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu-about">
<div class="top-dropdown-menu">
<div class="top-group" id="1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Would help if you add the closing tags for the 2 `<div>` that don't have them so we know if they are nested or not. See [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl It might but i believe the main problem is the relation between `.addClass('fadeIn')` and `m-fadeIn`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Agree...but never hurts to be clear and not need to make needless assumptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that try to add the class `fadeIn` but in your css it's called `m-fadeIn`.

Second you can make it a bit more simple like the example below:

```
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu-about').toggleClass('m-fadeIn m-fadeOut');
})
```

**Example**

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu-about').toggleClass('m-fadeIn m-fadeOut');
})
```

```css
.dropdown-menu-about {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  width: 500px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.m-fadeOut {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 300ms, opacity 300ms;
}

.m-fadeIn {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 300ms;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu-about m-fadeOut">
    <div class="top-dropdown-menu">
      <div class="top-group" id="1">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Do something</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This shorter method also works with the #about `li` but whenever I hover my mouse over the menu `div` I still fades out. What you know how to fix this?

Comment: @n212 try the Example now